# Laravel filter by integer column

Tags: php, laravel

Imagine you want to filter a table results you would do something like:

```
public function users(Request $request) {
    if ($request()->has('gender')) {
      $users = User::where('gender', request('gender'))
      ->paginate(5)
      ->appends('gender', request('gender'));
    } else {
      $users = User::->get();
    }
    return view('front.users', compact('users'));
  }
```

and it works just fine.

But in my case I try to filter my orders base on integer column which provides status of orders named `orderstatus_id`.

```
public function orders(Request $request) {
    if ($request()->has('orderstatus_id')) {
      $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->where('orderstatus_id', request('orderstatus_id'))
      ->paginate(5)
      ->appends('orderstatus_id', request('orderstatus_id'));
    } else {
      $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }
    return view('front.orders', compact('orders'));
  }
```

the problem is i get this error:

> Function name must be a string

on this part:

```
if ($request()->has('orderstatus_id')) {
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$request()
```

To this, if you want to use the global helper:

```
request()
```

Or to this:

```
$request
```

Both will do the same job.